# Wireshark thinks scapy packet's raw data is DNS (malformed packet)

Tags: networking, wireshark, scapy, broadcast

I'm trying to send a udp packet with scapy to the all the devices in my network with raw data: (`hello everyone`)

The packet looks like this:

```
packet = Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff") / IP(dst="255.255.255.0") / UDP(sport=8118) / "hello everyone"
```

```
packet.show()

###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  src       = (my mac address)
  type      = IPv4
###[ IP ]###
     version   = 4
     ihl       = None
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = None
     id        = 1
     flags     =
     frag      = 0
     ttl       = 64
     proto     = udp
     chksum    = None
     src       = 192.168.0.105
     dst       = 255.255.255.0
     \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
        sport     = 8118
        dport     = domain
        len       = None
        chksum    = None
###[ Raw ]###
           load      = 'hello everyone'
```

When I send the packet (`sendp(packet)`), wireshark says this is a malformed DNS packet:
[image]
[image]
[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're confusing Wireshark, due to you not specifying the destination port. If you don't specify a `dport` for `UDP`, it defaults to 53:

```
class UDP(Packet):
    name = "UDP"
    fields_desc = [ShortEnumField("sport", 53, UDP_SERVICES),
                   ShortEnumField("dport", 53, UDP_SERVICES),
                   ShortField("len", None),
                   XShortField("chksum", None), ]
```

Both ports actually do. 53 is for DNS though, so Wireshark is attempting to interpret your payload as DNS based on the port number.

Specify both `sport` and `dport` to ensure that your packet isn't misinterpreted as a DNS packet.

Comment: Correct! my bad